# How to get android battery level from ubuntu?

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, batterylevel

I'm trying to access the battery life of my android phone (Samsung Galaxy Y S5360) from my pc (im running ubuntu 14.04), but i can't find anything relevant and so i was wondering if there are any linux/unix tools for getting the battery life or maybe i can access a file on my phone which stores the battery life?

Optionally , i'd like to access other things like CPU usage, RAM usage etc as well.

Any kind of help would be nice. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make sure Android Debug Bridge, adb for short, is running, then enter this command `adb shell cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/capacity` in terminal

Comment: Do you know if there is any program that could possibly show this in the ubuntu indicator panel?

Comment: Maybe GSConnect or KDE Connect can help, but haven't used these so I'm not sure